# From where the so-named "elastica problem" is coming from?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, differential-equations

In a book by Cash et al, I see the mention of the so-called Elastica problem (pg 221 in the link [here](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT2425/Documents/Solving_Differential_Equations_In_R_Soetaert_K.pdf)).

The problem is presented as a system of ODEs,

$$
x' = \cos (\phi) 
$$

$$
y' = \sin (\phi) 
$$

$$
\phi' = \kappa
$$

$$
\kappa' = F \cos (\phi)
$$

and when I looked for where these ODEs come from I could not find a clear derivation anywhere. There are references to Bernoulli, Euler, but the formulation looked different. Does anyone know a book, reference that shows where these equations come from?

Thanks,

Comment: Reviewers: likely [proof](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2008/EECS-2008-103.pdf) that the question is on-topic.

Comment: So $\kappa'$ is just $x'$ times a constant, or is $F$ a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A. G. Greenhill, The applications of elliptic functions, Macmillan, London & NY, 1892,
pp. 87-88.

If you read French, a much clearer and more comprehensive discussion is in
G.-H. Halphen, Traite de fonctions elliptiques et de leurs applications,
2-eme partie, Paris Gauthier-Villars et fils, 1888.
Chapitre V.